# cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined in this.props.navigation.dispatch()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have to cutomize my drawer then I create a DrawerComponent with all items thas I need, I create a function with NavigationActions to dispatch my routes but it doesn't work. when I click on any item I have this error: cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefine

```
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
...
class DrawerComponent extends React.Component {

  navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}


  render()...
...
...

  <TouchableOpacity
   style={Styles.centerContent}
   onPress= {this.navigateToScreen('Messages')}

  >
   <IconIonic name="ios-mail" size={60} color= '#fff'/>
   <View>
    <Text>messages</Text>
   </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

In drawer

```
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
...
const DrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: { // entree (route name) : on peut la nommer comme on veut mais on prefere lui donner le meme nom que notre screen qu'on va afficher
      screen: HomeStackNavigation, // le screen qu'on va afficher IL DOIT ETRE UN STACK
    },
    Message: {
      screen: Messages,
    },
},
{
  drawerWidth: width*0.83,
  contentComponent: props => 
  {
    return(<DrawerComponent/>)
  },
  drawerPosition: 'left',
},
);
```

before that error, I had something like : undefined is not an object evaluating _this.props.navigation.dispatch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  contentComponent: props => {
    return <DrawerComponent {...props} />;
  };
}
```

Don't swallow `props`. Pass it to child component